# Python looping through list and adding sum to new list

Tags: loops, python-3.x, histogram

I have created a program which outputs 10 numbers based on probability. The program then sums the numbers in the list and adds this sum to a new list - `outcome1`.

My questions is how can I  loop this program so that it it outputs 10 numbers, say 15 times? each time summing the 10 numbers and adding the sum to the new list - `outcome1`. After completetion the new list - `outcome1` should have 15 numbers in it. I will then create a histogram of this list.

This is what i've tried so far, outputting 10 numbers with the sum works just not the looping for 15 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add amount and outcome1 to the for loop and clear output after each sum:

```
for j in range (15):
    for i in range(10):
            output.append(probability(prob, outcome))
    amount = sum(output)
    outcome1.append(amount)
    output = []

print(outcome1)
```